# Service discovery cache update in the case of node failure

Tags: caching, dns, mesos, service-discovery, grpc

I am trying to adopt a service discovery mechanism for my system. I have a bunch of nodes and they will communicate with each other via **gRpc**. Because in some frameworks like **Mesos**, a new node is brought up after it fails would possibly has **a different ip address and a different port**, I am thinking of using service discovery so that each node can have a cluster config that is agnostic to node failure.

My current options are to using DNS or strongly-consistent key-value store like etcd or zookeeper. **My problem is to understand how the cache of name mappings in healthy nodes get invalidated and updated when a node goes through down and up.**

The possible ways I can think of are:

1. When healthy nodes detect a connection problem, they invalidate
   their cache entry immediately and keep pulling the DNS registry
   until the node is connectable again.
2. When a node is down and up, the DNS registry broadcasts the events to all healthy nodes. Seems this may require heartbeats from DNS registry.
3. The cache in each node has a TTL field and within a TTL interval each node has to live with the node failure until the cache entry expires and pulls from the DNS registry again.

My question is which option (you can name more) is the case in reality and why it is better than other alternatives?

Comment: Did you take a look at [mesosdns](https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-dns) ? IF you are looking for a dns solution for Mesos, this is the most simple approach. 
And for the dynamic ports, if you use [Calico Project](https://www.projectcalico.org/), you can use fixed ports for each of your applications and get rid of this problem.

Comment: It looks like [Consul](https://www.consul.io/) fulfill your requirements. It has agent on every node and when node is down it's marked as unhealthy as well as all tasks its running. It uses gossip protocol to spread information about changes in cluster and raft as a consensus algorithm. It could be populated by periodically querying Mesos for state or if you use Marathon it can take advantage of events, see [marathon-consul](https://github.com/allegro/marathon-consul)